# What are process-based DES and event-based DES, exactly?

Tags: terminology, simulation

I have occasionally heard the terms "process-based DES" and "event-based DES".

For example, from [SimPy](https://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

> SimPy is a process-based discrete-event simulation framework based on standard Python.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-event_simulation#Three-Phased_Approach):

> The three-phase approach is a refinement of the event-based approach in which simultaneous events are ordered so as to make the most efficient use of computer resources.

[Ciw](https://ciw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Background/mechanisms.html) also mentions something that I would infer to be potentially event-based:

> Ciw uses the event scheduling approach [SW14], similar to the three-phase approach. In the event scheduling approach, three types of events take place: A Events move the clock forward, B Events are prescheduled events, and C Events are events that arise because a B Event has happened.

The citation above, [SW14], is

> Robinson. Simulation: the practice of model development and use. Palgrave Macmillan, 2014.

I got my hands on that book. I've implemented the three-phase approach described there. But I am still not 100% confident in my understanding of the distinction between "event-based" vs "process-based" DES.

I have also implemented some simulations using SimPy, but again not sure why exactly it is "process-based". It also keeps a min heap of events as did the three-phase approach implementation.

Can the distinction be made explicit (and formal, if possible)?